# karate chrome(chromium-browser) driver configuration

Tags: integration-testing, karate

I need to launch a url for UI testing in a KarateDSL scenario.

I have configured, in `Feature -> Background`:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: 'chromesh' }
```

Where, `chromesh` is a executable (chromium-browser launching) bash script in `~/.local/bin`.

At run it always seems to be using the default driver config:

```
18:38:09.781 [null_1552396089768] ERROR c.intuit.karate.shell.CommandThread - command error: [/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=/home/../target/null_1552396089768, --headless] - Cannot run program "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" (in directory "target/null_1552396089768"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Karate version: 0.9.1

Is there any configuration I'm missing or done wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IntelliJ - there's this known problem where it does not honor the system environmental variables in some situations.

Try running your test from the command line via maven, e.g.

```
mvn test -Dtest=MyJunitRunner
```

Comment: oh yes, have been using IntelliJ, will retry via mvn, thanks!